# How to make a SQL query to count sessions consist of several action

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm quite new at SQL, and I don`t understand how to make one query. I have a table, which consists of three columns: user_id, timestamp, event_code. And it looks like this:

```
    user_id     timestamp                 event_code
    ------------------------------------------------
0   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:53:46.937Z    2000
1   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:54:17.519Z    2000
2   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:54:56.302Z    2000
3   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:54:56.387Z    3010
4   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:55:03.253Z    3110
5   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:55:06.279Z    4070
6   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:55:06.913Z    4070
7   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:55:07.546Z    4070
8   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:55:07.979Z    4070
9   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:55:08.566Z    4070
```

I need to count the number of sessions during a day. The session is a sequence of three events (2020 -> 3020 -> 4020). There can be different events between these three, but time delta between 4020 and 2020 can't be more then 1 hour.

As a result I expect such table

```
    user_id     start_session       end_session
    ----------------------------------------------------
0   0001e90f    2019-09-06T17:53:46 2019-09-06T18:50:46
1   0002e90f    2019-09-06T17:59:46 2019-09-06T18:37:46
2   0003e90f    2019-09-06T16:23:46 2019-09-06T17:00:00
3   0004e90f    2019-09-06T17:09:46 2019-09-06T17:58:27
4   0001e90f    2019-09-07T12:33:46 2019-09-07T12:55:20
5   0002e90f    2019-09-07T17:53:46 2019-09-06T18:50:46
```

As I understand, I need to select timestamp of 2020 event and timestamp of 4020 one and to count a delta for every user. Then I need to group them by hour and count number of such users_id(their deltas). But I don'd understand how to write such condition, and how can I indicate that there should be event 3020 between them.

Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: can you please share whats your expected result?

Comment: I`ve added my expectation and DB type to the tags.

Comment: The data you provided in the example and the data in the expected result does not seem to match up. Where do the times in the expected result come from?

Comment: I've pointed, that I need to count sessions. So, start_time in the result is the timestamp of event_code 2020 from the example. end_session is the timestamp of event_code 4020. There is at least one event between them (3020), but we don`t interested in its timestamp, and there can be other different events, we are also not interested in them. If there is no 3020 event between 2020 and 4020, we don't count it as a session, and if time delta between 4020 and 2020 more then 1 hour, we also don't count it as a session.

Comment: @Stas . . . Why doesn't the sample data have the event codes that you claim define a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to get the "future" information and then simple logic to define the sessions.

This will work, assuming you have some discipline in your data.  If the data is uncontrolled -- such as multiple 2020s in a row -- then I would suggest that you ask a new question with more explanation.

So, the sessions are:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when event_code = 3020 then timestamp end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as next_3020,
             min(case when event_code = 4020 then timestamp end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as next_4020
      from t
     ) t
where event_code = 2020 and
      next_3020 > timestamp and
      next_4020 > next_3020 and
      next_4020 < timestamp + interval '1 hour';
```

The number per day is then:

```
select timestamp::date, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when event_code = 3020 then timestamp end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as next_3020,
             min(case when event_code = 4020 then timestamp end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc) as next_4020
      from t
     ) t
where event_code = 2020 and
      next_3020 > timestamp and
      next_4020 > next_3020 and
      next_4020 < timestamp + interval '1 hour'
group by timestamp::date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It is not a completely correct script but maybe it will give the idea

```
SELECT 
s1.userid, 
s1.event_code,
s2.event_code,
s1.timestamp,
s2.timestamp
FROM test AS s1
INNER JOIN test AS s2 ON s1.userid = s2.userid
WHERE 
s1.event_code = '2020' AND 
s2.event_code = '4020' AND 
TIMEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(s2.timestamp,'%H:%i:%s'), DATE_FORMAT(s1.timestamp, '%H:%i:%s')) >= 0 AND TIMEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(s2.timestamp,'%H:%i:%s'), DATE_FORMAT(s1.timestamp, '%H:%i:%s')) <= MAKETIME(1, 0, 0)
```